# Pass large amount of parameters between jobs

Tags: jenkins

I have two Jenkins jobs that tun on separate computers. On computer 1 I read properties file and use it for environment variables. But i need the same file on PC 2 and it only exist on the first one. When the first Jenkins job finishes it starts the second one and it can pass parameters file via job but I have to receive with creation of separate parameter with Parameterized Trigger Plugin for each parameter, and I have a lot and don`t want to do so. Is there simple solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget Jenkins 1 and the plugins Parameterized Trigger Plugin. Using Jenkins 2, here's an example of your need:

```
node ("pc1") {
stage "step1"
stash name: "app", includes: "properties_dir/*"
}

node ("pc2") {
stage "step2"
dir("dir_to_unstash") {
    unstash "app"
} 
}
```