# How to pass large amount of text between Jenkins jobs?

Tags: string, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, large-data

I work with a Jenkins job that calls a downstream parameterized job, whose parameter is a JSON-format string.

Occasionally, the downstream job fails. The volume of error text is substantial, and I think the relevant content is:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "git" (in directory "/home/user/workspace/MyJob@script"): error=7, Argument list too long
```

...which I think is telling me that the downstream job's string parameter, populated by the upstream job, is too large.
If I manually launch the job and toy with the string length I can induce job success or failure (with the above error), which I think substantiates my guess that the string parameter length is the problem.

According to this post, the maximum length of a Jenkins string parameter is not documented or publicized, possibly because it is a function of several variables that makes the answer different between instances: [what's the string length limit of jenkins string parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50831470/whats-the-string-length-limit-of-jenkins-string-parameter)

**Question: What are standard/recommended methods of passing long strings between Jenkins jobs?**

I can imagine ad hoc solutions, such as writing my JSON content to a file at a location known to downstream jobs...or the upstream job passing the filepath as a parameter to the downstream job -- but I'd prefer to use standard/accepted solutions over ad hoc ones.

Researching the issue, I ran into `stash()`/`unstash()` in posts such as this: [Pass large amount of parameters between jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45530894/pass-large-amount-of-parameters-between-jobs)
But the Jenkins Snippet Generator says `stash()` and `unstash()` are for use between stages *in the same build* -- which is not my use-case: I need to pass strings between jobs.

Other posts like this suggest `archiveArtifacts()`: [Documentation on archiveArtifacts command in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47877531/documentation-on-archiveartifacts-command-in-jenkins) -- but how do you "unarchive" an artifact? In the "Sample Step" drop-down list in my Jenkins Snippet Generator, I don't see `copyArtifacts()` or anything else that appears to be an analog to `archiveArtifacts()`.